# Synaptics Property Drivers

Tags: drivers, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

I have a Toshiba notebook with Synaptics touchpad. I would like to set 3 finger swipe and some other gestures but they are not available in settings. This [official page](http://www.synaptics.com/en/gesture-suite-linux.php) says there is a driver suite for linux but it also says to be downloaded from the manufacturer. Toshiba doesn't provide any driver for linux, anyone know a way to get this property driver? (Property drivers page doesn't detect the synaptics)

Second question is as the double tap and click results in a right click, I would like to disable right click completely so I won't misclick.

OS : Ubuntu 15.04
Regards.

Comment: Maybe "proprietary" drivers?

Answer (score 0):

Kernel driver for your touchpad supports these kind of gestures. You do not need to install any drivers.

You can disable 2-finger tap by

```
synclient TapButton2=0
```

in terminal.

To make this setting permanent you can add this command as automatically started application.

As far as I know, unity (Ubuntu desktop Environment) does not support other gestures. Correct me, if I am wrong.